# How to continue searching in the found reqexp result?

Tags: regex

There is a certain string that I find using regexp, is there an opportunity to check whether there is another one in the found string

For example, I found a string using

```
(?i)((function|procedure)+(.+?(?=stdcall)))
```

And I want to check if there is a result in it for

```
(.+?(?=((\s)|(\:))String))
```

For example, it should find

```
Function Test(aTest: String; const aPluginCall: TObject): integer; stdcall; export;
```

But skip

```
Function Test(aTest: AnsiString; const aPluginCall: TObject): integer; stdcall; export;
```

or

```
Function Test: integer; stdcall; export;
```

Comment: `(?i)(function|procedure)(.+?[\s:]String.*?)(?=stdcall)` or `(?i)(function|procedure)((?:(?!function|procedure).)*?[\s:]String.*?)(?=stdcall)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary to look for it in the previous result, otherwise it goes beyond

Comment: Where does it "go beyond"? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RVHcBi/2). What is wrong?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/28838

Comment: Then use two tempered greedy tokens, `(?si)(function|procedure)((?:(?!function|procedure|stdcall).)*[\s:]String(?:(?!function|procedure).)*)(?=stdcall)`

Comment: you are the god of regexp, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?si)(function|procedure)((?:(?!function|procedure|stdcall).)*[\s:]String(?:(?!function|procedure).)*)(?=stdcall)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/28839).

*Details*:

- `(?si)` - `s` enables `.` to match line break chars and `i` enables cas e insensitive matching
- `(function|procedure)` - Group 1: `function` or `procedure`
- `((?:(?!function|procedure|stdcall).)*[\s:]String(?:(?!function|procedure).)*)` - Group 2:

  - `(?:(?!function|procedure|stdcall).)*` - a char other than line break chars, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `function`, `procedure` or `stdcall` char sequences
  - `[\s:]` - a whitespace or `:`
  - `String` - a `String` string
  - `(?:(?!function|procedure).)*` - a char other than line break chars, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `function` or `procedure` char sequences
- `(?=stdcall)` - a positive lookahead that requires `stdcall` text to appear immediately to the right of the current location.